# Shimano Sora FC-3503 chainrings

Tags: shimano, crankset, chainring, compatibility

I want to change my 50T chainring of my Shimano Sora FC-3503 crankset.

Do I have to buy the same one or other chainrings are also compatible with it?

If yes could you give me some light which ones ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace it with what?  What's your goal?  Different gearing?  Less weight?

Comment: The goal was just to change it. Unfortunately FC-3503 is hard to get in my location, but i found in my local store SHIMANO Claris FC-2403 50T 130BCD. Will it be compatible with my crankset ? Will it be compatible with my CS-HG50-9 + CN-HG93 ?

Comment: Are you replacing just the chainring, or the entire crankset?  The [Sora FC-5303](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/sora-3500/FC-3503.html) looks to be a Hollowtech II crankset, while the [Claris 2403](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/claris-2400/FC-2403.html) looks like it's an Octalink crankset, which means it uses a different bottom bracket.  Or are you just changing [the chainring](https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/chainrings/shimano-sora-fc3503-130mm-bcd-5-arm-outer-chainring-d-type-black-50t/?geoc=US)?

Comment: Just a chainring, the biggest one: 50T.

Answer (score 2):

The 50 tooth chainring is a standard 5 bolt, 130 BCD chainring. There are other options available that will fit, but most 130 BCD will have 53 teeth, so you may have to hunt around for a bit to find a 50 tooth that you like.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I've found that claris group has also 130BCD 50T. Problem solved.